# To Get unique Values and Calculate the sum of amount using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below code, I want to print values into two section.

The first section is working good i have display vat,total price,material description,code etc

In second section i want to display the unique vat and its amount from first section.

First Section :  - Working

```
Code  MaterialDesc  Vat Total Price
11     XXX          10%   500
12     yyy          10 %  800
13     zzz          5%    100
```

Second Section : - Not Working

```
VAT Amount:
10%  1300
5%   100 

 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPrint" OnClick="lnkPrint_Click" OnClientClick = "return PrintPanel();" runat="server" CommandName="Print"
                            Text="Print" />
function PrintPanel() {
              var today = new Date();
              var dd = today.getDate();
              var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!

              var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
              if (dd < 10) {
                  dd = '0' + dd
              }
              if (mm < 10) {
                  mm = '0' + mm
              }
              var today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
//              var map = new Object();
              var txtPrint = "";
              //txtPrint = '<table><h2 align=\"center\">Food Store</h2><h3 align=center>109,Eswaran Koil street,Puducherry-607001 </h3 ><h4 align=center>Tin No:34310000244,   Ph:0413-2227546-49</h4><h5 align=center><U>Cridit Bill</U></h5>';
              txtPrint = '<table><h3 align=center>Food Store.</h3 ><h4 align=center>' + currentLocationAddress + '</h4><h5 align=center><U>Cridit Bill</U></h5>';

              txtPrint += '<table width=\"100%\"><tr><td width=\"25%\"><b>Customer Name :</b></td><td width=\"25%\">' + currentCustomer + '</td>';
              txtPrint += '<td width=\"25%\"><b>Invoice No :</b></td><td width=\"25%\">' + document.getElementById("<%=txtInvoiceNO.ClientID%>").value + '</td></tr></table>';

              txtPrint += '<table width=\"100%\"><tr><td width=\"25%\"><b>Address:</b></td><td width=\"25%\">' + currentCustomerAddress + '</td>';
              txtPrint += '<td width=\"25%\"><b>Date :</b></td><td width=\"25%\">' + today + '</td></tr></table>';

              txtPrint += '<table width=\"36%\"><tr><td width=\"\"20%><b>Phone No:</b></td><td width=\"20%\">' + ContactNo + '</td>';
              //txtPrint += '// <td width=\"25%\"><b>TIN :</b></td><td width=\"25%\"></td>'
              txtPrint += '</tr></table>';

              txtPrint += '</table><BR>';
      txtPrint += '<hr width=\"100%\" align=left><table width=\"100%\" cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0><tr>';
                  txtPrint += '<th width=150px align=center><b> Code</b></th>';
                  txtPrint += '<th width=50px align=center><b>Barcode</b></th>';
                  txtPrint += '<th width=\"80%\" align=left><b>Material Description</b></th>';

                  txtPrint += '<th width=\"10%\" align=center><b>Unit Price</b></th>';
                  txtPrint += '<th width=\"10%\" align=center><b>VAT(%)</b></th>';
                  txtPrint += '<th width=\"10%\" align=center><b>Quantity</b></th>';
                  txtPrint += '<th width=\"10%\" align=center><b>Price</b></th>';
                  txtPrint += '<th width=\"10%\" align=center><b>VAT Amount</b></th>';
                  txtPrint += '<th width=\"10%\" align=center><b>Total Price</b></th></tr>';
                  txtPrint += '<table><table><hr width=\"100%\" align=left>';

                  $.each(invoiceData, function (i, item) {
                      var ProductName = GetProductName(item.ProductID);
                      var UnitPrice = item.UnitPrice;
                      var ProductCode = item.ProductCode;
                      var VAT = item.VAT;
                      var Quantity = item.Quantity; // item.QuantityRequested;
                      var PriceWithVAT = item.UnitPrice;
                      var VATAmount = CalcVATAmount(UnitPrice, VAT);
                      var TotalPrice = item.Total;
                      var Barcode = GenerateBarcodeImg(ProductCode);





                      txtPrint += '<table width=\"100%\"><tr><td width=\"10%\" align=left>' + ProductCode + '</td>';

                      txtPrint += '<td width=\"10%\" align=center>' + imgContent + '</td>';

                      txtPrint += '<td width=\"40%\" align=center>' + ProductName + '</td>';

                      txtPrint += '<td width=\"10%\" align=center>' + UnitPrice + '</td>';

                      txtPrint += '<td width=\"10%\" align=center>' + VAT + '</td>';

                      txtPrint += '<td width=\"10%\" align=center>' + Quantity + '</td>';

                      txtPrint += '<td width=\"10%\" align=center>' + PriceWithVAT + '</td>';

                      txtPrint += '<td width=\"10%\" align=center>' + VATAmount + '</td>';



                      txtPrint += '<td width=\"10%\" align=center>' + TotalPrice + '</td></tr></table>';


                  });

                  txtPrint += '</table></table><hr width=\"100%\" align=left></table>';
                  txtPrint += '<table width=\"100%\"><tr>';
                  txtPrint += '<td width=\"85%\" align=right ><b>Invoice Total Value :</b></td><td width=\"15%\"  align=center>' + document.getElementById("<%=hidTotalCost.ClientID%>").value + '</td><tr></table>';

                  var UniqVAT = $.unique(VAT);


                  txtPrint += '</table><BR>';

                  txtPrint += '<hr width=\"50%\" align=left><table width=\"50%\" cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0><tr>';
                  txtPrint += '<th width=10px align=center><b> VAT%</b></th>';
                  txtPrint += '<th width=10px align=center><b>Amount</b></th>';
                  txtPrint += '<th width=\"10%\" align=left><b>VAT AMOUNT</b></th>';


                  txtPrint += '<table><table><hr width=\"50%\" align=left>';

                  txtPrint += '<table width=\"100%\"><tr><td width=\"10%\" align=left>' + UniqVAT + '</td>';
 txtPrint += 'Thanking you,<BR>  SVGFPPL.<BR><BR>';

              txtPrint += "(Authorised Signatory)";

              var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
              printWindow.document.write('<body >');
              printWindow.document.write(txtPrint);
              printWindow.document.write('</body>');
              printWindow.document.close();
              setTimeout(function () {
                  printWindow.print();
              }, 500);
              return false;
          }
```

Comment: i think you should filter the one you want to show at source of data level rather than in javascript. Be it database or json data. Thats far easier

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of map while iterating table and store `VAT` in a map and sum up all values to use it later. See below code

**NOTE** - I did not understand the table structure you followed as I can see lots of `<table>` tags starting / ending. Please make sure you have proper html table structure.

```
//define map here
var map = new Object();

txtPrint += '<hr width=\"100%\" align=left><table width=\"100%\" cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0><tr>';
txtPrint += '<th width=150px align=center><b> Code</b></th>';
txtPrint += '<th width=50px align=center><b>Barcode</b></th>';
txtPrint += '<th width=\"80%\" align=left><b>Material Description</b></th>';

txtPrint += '<th width=\"10%\" align=center><b>Unit Price</b></th>';
txtPrint += '<th width=\"10%\" align=center><b>VAT(%)</b></th>';
txtPrint += '<th width=\"10%\" align=center><b>Quantity</b></th>';
txtPrint += '<th width=\"10%\" align=center><b>Price</b></th>';
txtPrint += '<th width=\"10%\" align=center><b>VAT Amount</b></th>';
txtPrint += '<th width=\"10%\" align=center><b>Total Price</b></th></tr>';
txtPrint += '<table><table><hr width=\"100%\" align=left>';

  $.each(invoiceData, function (i, item) {
      var ProductName = GetProductName(item.ProductID);
      var UnitPrice = item.UnitPrice;
      var ProductCode = item.ProductCode;
      var VAT = item.VAT;
      var Quantity = item.Quantity; // item.QuantityRequested;
      var PriceWithVAT = item.UnitPrice;
      var VATAmount = CalcVATAmount(UnitPrice, VAT);
      var TotalPrice = item.Total;
      var Barcode = GenerateBarcodeImg(ProductCode);





      txtPrint += '<table width=\"100%\"><tr><td width=\"10%\" align=left>' + ProductCode + '</td>';

      txtPrint += '<td width=\"10%\" align=center>' + imgContent + '</td>';

      txtPrint += '<td width=\"40%\" align=center>' + ProductName + '</td>';

      txtPrint += '<td width=\"10%\" align=center>' + UnitPrice + '</td>';

      txtPrint += '<td width=\"10%\" align=center>' + VAT + '</td>';

      txtPrint += '<td width=\"10%\" align=center>' + Quantity + '</td>';

      txtPrint += '<td width=\"10%\" align=center>' + PriceWithVAT + '</td>';

      txtPrint += '<td width=\"10%\" align=center>' + VATAmount + '</td>';



      txtPrint += '<td width=\"10%\" align=center>' + TotalPrice + '</td></tr></table>';

      //add VAT to map
      var vatTotalAmount = parseInt(map.get(VAT)) || 0;
      vatTotalAmount += parseInt(VATAmount);
      map[VAT] = vatTotalAmount;
  });


      txtPrint += '</table></table><hr width=\"100%\" align=left></table>';
      txtPrint += '<table width=\"100%\"><tr>';
      txtPrint += '<td width=\"85%\" align=right ><b>Invoice Total Value :</b></td><td width=\"15%\"  align=center>' + document.getElementById("<%=hidTotalCost.ClientID%>").value + '</td><tr></table>';


      txtPrint += '</table><BR>';

      txtPrint += '<hr width=\"50%\" align=left><table width=\"50%\" cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0><tr>';
      txtPrint += '<th width=10px align=center><b> VAT%</b></th>';
      txtPrint += '<th width=10px align=center><b>Amount</b></th>';
      txtPrint += '<th width=\"10%\" align=left><b>VAT AMOUNT</b></th>';


      txtPrint += '<table><table><hr width=\"50%\" align=left>';
     $.each(map, function (k, v)
   {
      txtPrint += '<table width=\"100%\"><tr><td width=\"10%\" align=left>' + k + '</td><td width=\"10%\" align=left>' + v + '</td>';
   }
```

Comment: Issue is not solved now on click print it is getting page loaded.

Comment: I want to display distinct values and it total amount as example in above

Comment: Your code is too long to understand , please make it short and running. I tried to run it on jsfiddle but lots of error, please share jsfiddle link so that I can help you better.